# dynamic manipulation of django admin form

Tags: django, admin, customization

I have a modified admin form, where I added a field that shall modify the values of the current model's parent object. Now, depending on the user, I need to

- alter the queryset of that extra field
- set another field as readonly (or better, even hide it completely)

Basically my code below works as I'd expect it. A superuser gets the whole queryset and the other field is *not* readonly. All other users get a limited queryset and the other field *is* readonly. However, once I open that site in a different browser and as a non-superuser, even the superuser get the same result as the non-superusers. Seems like django somehow caches the result? If I put some print statements inside the conditional branches though, they get printed correctly. So the method still gets called each time and seems to still perform these steps. Only with a wrong outcome.

Is that a caching problem? Am I doing something entirely wrong? Can it be a bug in the django test server?

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(MultishopProductAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if obj is not None:
        form.declared_fields['categories'].initial = obj.product.category.all()
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        user_site = request.user.get_profile().site
        form.declared_fields['categories'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(site__id=user_site.id)
        self.readonly_fields = ('virtual_sites', )
        if obj is not None:
            form.declared_fields['categories'].initial = obj.product.category.filter(site__id=user_site.id)
    return form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find a really clever way to do what I wanted with django admin's custom methods. What I ended up doing now is implementing the admin's `change_view`, setting up my own form manually and performing all my custom initializations from there.

I then provided a custom template by setting `change_form_template`, which is simply extending `admin/change_form.html` but rendering my own form instead of the default one. I also set `extra_context['adminform'] = None` so the default admin form gets removed.

That way I can now customize my form the way I need it to be but still use all the other admin conveniences. So far it seems to work very nicely. Not the very most elegant solution either I think, but the best I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it wrong. In Django 1.2+ you can use [get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977206/538471):

> The ModelAdmin is only instantiated once for all requests that it receives. So when you define the readonly fields like that, you're setting it across the board permanently.

Regarding altering the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset). From the documentation:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you, that already solved my readonly field issue. The `queryset` method is not what I'm looking for however. I would usually use `formfield_for_manytomany` on the categories attribute. Since that's not part of the model however, `formfield_for_manytomany` doesn't get called for that field. Any other method where I could limit it's queryset then?

Comment: And also pass the initial data for it, of course. I'd actually expect that to be rather simple, but I couldn't find anything other than the usual initial= param, which doesn't suffice for my needs though.

Comment: What are you trying to filter and why?

Comment: Model A (what that code excerpt is for) is something like a "proxy" to Model B. It's not subclassed, but Model A needs to update a categories M2M field of Model B. That works all good and fine that way, but for easier usage I need to limit the choices for the categories. Also, I need to have it reflect the current choices via initial data, depending on the user (so I need the request).

Comment: Then you need formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: `formfield_for_manytomany` and `formfield_for_foreignkey` unfortunately only get invoked for fields that actually come from the model. Not for fields you add additionally like this is in my case.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on dan-klasson's anwer: Do not ever set instance attributes in any ModelAdmin method (like `self.readonly_fields`) to prevent issues like the one you described. Only use Django ModelAdmin's options (which are class-level) or methods to manipulate any behavior. Regarding readonly fields, you can use the `ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields` method which has this signature: `get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None)`.